# How to exclude rows based on multi column value conditions in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

There's pandas dataframe ad below:

```
email             score
a@domain.com      A
b@domain.com      A
c@domain.com      C
d@domain.com      B
```

I want to exclude rows with `email` `a@domain.com` and `c@domain.com`.Expect result as below:

```
email            score
b@domain.com      A
d@domain.com      B
```

I tried 3 times but failed:

```
df=df[df.email !='a@domain.com' & df.email !='c@domain.com' ]
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]


df=df[df.email !='a@domain.com' && df.email !='c@domain.com' ]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


df=df[df.email !='a@domain.com' | 'c@domain.com' ]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to surround it by parenthesis:

```
df = df[(df.email != 'a@domain.com') & (df.email != 'c@domain.com')]
```

That said, it would be easier with `isin`:

```
df = df[~df.email.isin(['a@domain.com', 'c@domain.com'])]
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is gonna be the expected output.

Comment: what's `~` in `df = df[~df.email.isin(['a@domain.com', 'c@domain.com'])]`?

Comment: @kittygirl the `isin` means if it contains any element in the list, but since those are the ones you don't want, use that sign to get the opposite of it and remove those.

Comment: Why not `!` but `~`?

Comment: @kittygirl That's a very good point, but in pandas, it is different, you have to use `~`